# HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header in Django

Tags: python, django, apache

I wrote a simple check in django which requires an access token to be passed along in some requests (I'm using a decorator).

```
    authorization = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', None)

    # Forbid access when no access token, or an invalid one, is provided
    form = AccessTokenForm({ 'access_token': authorization })
    if not form.is_valid():
        raise exceptions.HttpDeniedException()
```

This has been working fine with django's development server, but recently I deployed using Apache and now it doesn't work anymore, as the `authorisation` variable is `None`. Has anyone faced something similiar before? The client is passing the header as `Authorization`; again, this is working fine in localhost, but not on the remote server.

Edit: I found [this](http://forum.alwaysdata.com/viewtopic.php?id=2299), and it seems that it should work, but it doesn't. Actually, I didn't even have an .htaccess file, and adding one doesn't seem to have taken any effect at all. Here are the contents:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(media/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(static/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URL} !(dispatch.fcgi)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L,E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

The thing is, I'm not even sure Apache is using this at all..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems there's a ticket for this issue [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/488). Just add the following to apache2.conf:

```
WSGIPassAuthorization on
```